# Bind history to back button in Worklight using JQuery and HTML5 History

Tags: jquery, load, browser-history, ibm-mobilefirst

I have seen a few discussions for this but they all assume that there is a button on the page for the user to go back. I am creating a multi-page form using jQuery load and unload in Worklight. For those familiar with WL, this is based off their multi-page app sample. Basically, when the web app loads, it uses the pagePort to display the content:

```
function wlCommonInit(){

$("#pagePort").load("www/firstPage.html", function(){
    currentPage.init();
});
}
```

At this point the user is seeing the landing page which has a continue button:

```
<input type="button" value="Load Page1.html" id="LoadPage1Button" onclick="currentPage.loadPage(1);" />
```

When the user clicks the button, the pagePort content is switched out with the next page that begins the form entry:

```
currentPage.init = function () {
  history.pushState({
    page: 2
  }, "Page2", "yourInformation");
};

currentPage.loadPage = function (pageIndex) {
  $("#pagePort").load("www/yourInformation" + ".html", function () {
    currentPage.init();
  });
};
```

At this point, the url is changes to ../blah/firstPage.html#yourInformation and the user can continue on to the next page of the form after entering their information and again clicking continue. Note that this multi-page form only has 1 continue button on each page and there are no other buttons available...don't ask me why...

So the only option they have to go back is the browser back button which is available since I am just manipulating the browser history with the history.pushState. However, when I click the browser back button, only the URL changes but not the page.

So my question is... is there a simple way to bind the back button to the URL history that I am creating by using the pushState to append the url? All I need to do is allow the user to hit the back button and be allowed to go to the first page.

firstPage.html JS file that that loads the page yourInformation.html page after user clicks continue:
    currentPage = {};

```
currentPage.init = function () {
  WL.Logger.debug("firstPage :: init");
  history.pushState({
    page: 0
  }, "firstPage");
  history.back(0);
};

currentPage.loadPage = function (pageIndex) {
  $("#pagePort").load("www/yourInformation" + ".html", function () {
    currentPage.init();
  });
};
currentPage.unload = function () {
  $('#pagePort').html('');
    for (var att in currentPage) {
    delete currentPage[att];
 }
};
```

Oh and Plug-Ins are not an option...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WL.App.overrideBackButton`.

```
WL.App.overrideBackButton(backFunc);
function backFunc(){
    // put your logic here.
}
```